# Is this relation a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I've been told that this relation is not a function:

$\Big\{(x, y) \ \Big\vert \ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}, \, x \geq y \Big\}$

But I can't see why not, every element of the domain $x$, is mapped to some element of the codomain. The extreme case, $0$ is mapped to $0$?

Comment: What is your definition of "function"?  Have you checked *all* the clauses in that definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element is indeed "mapped", but the problem is that it is mapped multiple times, which is why the relation is not a function. Indeed for instance if $x = 2$ then clearly the elements of the set $\{1,0,-1\}$ are all in relation with $x$.

Comment: Right that makes sense, one to many is not a function. Thank you